# How to access public method of subclass from it's abstract parent Java 8

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

This question is a bit confusing and simple at the same time but I am unable to get to a resolution. I will do my best to articulate.

How to evoke a public method of a subclass of an abstract super class?

Example:

```
public abstract class SuperClass extends SomethingElse implements SomeOtherThing {
    protected final PlmlForm plForm;

    String getData() {
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private Report report;

    String getReport() {
    }
}

main(String[] args) {
    SuperClass s = something();
}
```

how can I do something like `s.getReport()` ?

And yes you can evoke abstract classes.

Comment: `s` is the name reference to the parent class SuperClass

Comment: Well, 
it is understood

Comment: solved, I'll post my answer now

Comment: Ready, tell me if it served you

Comment: Please, consider marking my answer as accepted if it served you

Comment: Thanks @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán it did serve me well

Comment: And thanks to you, you helped me reach the 1000's reputation ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an object of type `SubClass` public so that you can access the instance `SubClass` from `SuperClass`

```
public abstract class SuperClass extends SomethingElse implements SomeOtherThing {
protected final PlmlForm plForm = null;

   String getData() { }

   // How can I do something like s.getReport()?
   // This is the way you call getReport
   String getReport()
   {
      return new SubClass().s.getReport();

      //If s is static...
      return SubClass.s.getReport();
   }

   //Illustrative example
   Subclass sub = new SubClass();
   sub.s.getReport(); // Here the magic happens
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
   private Report report = null;

  /*
   * You create the object s that refers to Subclass
   */
   public SuperClass/SubClass s = this;
   //Or
   public static SuperClass/SubClass s = this;
   /********************************************/

    String getReport() { }
}

main(String[] args) {
    SuperClass s = this; // As SubClass extends from Superclass, for Java, it is the same as Superclass
    SubClass s = this; // And here it is the same, since SubClass and SuperClass in this case are the same
}
```